# label within fieldcontain hidden behind the input field

Tags: android, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I use a `div` with `data-role="fieldcontain"` to order input elements with their respective labels (and support several screen sizes). As an example, see following code:

```
<div style="border-bottom-width:0;" data-role="fieldcontain" data-type="vertical">
  <label for="ti_brutto">Label</label>
  <input name="ti_brutto" id="ti_brutto" style="text-align: right" type="number">

  <label for="kirchenonoff">Slightlylargerlabel</label>
  <select name ="kirchenonoff" id="kirchenonoff" data-role="slider">
    <option value="false">Nein</option>
    <option value="true">Ja</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDeKq/6/)

However, for some reason, the label is being partially hidden behind the input fields for some sizes, while it should display the input field smaller or in the next row. How ca I fix it?

Working with JQuery mobile, for an Android App.

Comment: `label.ui-slider { margin-right: 20px !important }` should fix it. Or width, whichever you like.

Comment: If I use that, the input field would be more to the right than the slider. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDeKq/7/)

Comment: in this case, you need to modify both, input and label.

Comment: or use girds http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vDeKq/8/

Comment: the label is till behind the input field on the jsFiddle

Comment: Now http://jsfiddle.net/vDeKq/9/

Comment: The label still gets hidden behind input if you make the site smaller.

Comment: now? http://jsfiddle.net/vDeKq/10/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32834/discussion-between-simplebob-and-omar)